# Find object in an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to implement some sort of hasObject function with underscore.js.

Example:

```
var Collection = {
    this.items: [];
    this.hasItem: function(item) {
        return _.find(this.items, function(existingItem) { //returns undefined
            return item % item.name == existingItem.name;
        });
    }
};

Collection.items.push({ name: "dev.pus", account: "stackoverflow" });
Collection.items.push({ name: "margarett", account: "facebook" });
Collection.items.push({ name: "george", account: "google" });

Collection.hasItem({ name: "dev.pus", account: "stackoverflow" }); // I know that the name would already be enough...
```

For some reason underscores find returns undefined...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is it that you think the `%` operator does?

Comment: You say you want to find out whether an object contains another object, yet you seem to be deciding this purely on whether the `name` property is the same. So should the entire object match, or just the `name` property?

Comment: @Utkanos as you see in the comment it was just testing the name but it would be good to know how to test the whole object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are reading underscore documentation too literally, where
they have:

```
var even = _.find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
```

However, this doesn't make any sense for your case, you just want to see if the `.name` property is equal to
some other object's `.name`, like this:

```
var Collection = {
    items: [],

    hasItem: function(item) {
        return _.find(this.items, function(existingItem) { //returns undefined
            return item.name === existingItem.name;
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check both values for the name and the account.

```
var Collection = {
  this.items: [];
  this.hasItem: function(target) {
    return _.find(this.items, function(item) {
      return item.name === target.name && item.acount === target.account;
    });
  }
};
```

Have you considered using [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)? It fulfills all your collection management needs and uses underscore's methods too.

```
// create a collection
var accounts = new Backbone.Collection();

// add models
accounts.add({name: 'dev.pus', account: 'stackoverflow'});
accounts.add({name: 'margarett', account: 'facebook'});
accounts.add({name: 'george', account: 'google'});

// getting an array.
var results = accounts.where({ name: 'dev.pus', account: 'stackoverflow' });
```